# Reversing names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a Name column like this:

[image: Names col in DF]

How can I use pandas to reverse the names in the format "xxx, xxx" efficiently? Also if you have other string cleaning tips for munging names like these I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) to perform regex string substitutions:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'(.+),\s+(.+)', r'\2 \1')
```

The regex pattern `(.+), (.+)` means

```
(      begin group #1
  .+   match 1-or-more of any character
)      end group #1
,      match a literal comma 
\s+    match 1-or-more whitespace characters
(      begin group #2
  .+   match 1-or-more of any character
)      end group #2
```

The second argument `r'\2 \1'`, tells `str.replace` to replace substrings that match the pattern with group #2 followed by a space, followed by group #1.

---

```
import pandas as pd
names = '''\
John Snow
Black, Jack
Jim Bean/
Draper, Don
'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': names.splitlines()})
#           Name
# 0    John Snow
# 1  Black, Jack
# 2    Jim Bean/
# 3  Draper, Don

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'(.+),\s+(.+)', r'\2 \1')
```

yields

```
         Name
0   John Snow
1  Jack Black
2   Jim Bean/
3  Don Draper
```

Comment: I believe OP asked for any other cleaning tips.  You could easily (as I'm sure you know) add a `/?` at the end of your regex to capture any trailing `/`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the answers unutbu, Stefan, and Andreas Hsieh! I'm accepting this one because it is the most flexible and for the regex explanation. @Stefan your answer is quite elegant and I will probably use concepts from it in my solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like this with `reverse` function:

```
d = {'name':['Bran Stark','Jon Snow','Rhaegar Targaryen']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['new name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x : ', '.join(reversed(x.split(' '))))
print(df['new name'])

0           Stark, Bran
1             Snow, Jon
2    Targaryen, Rhaegar
```