# How to reverse strings in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is like,

```
ID   col1
1    Michael Owen
2    Stephen Curry
3    Messi, Lionel
4    James, LeBron
```

I tried to reverse the order of those names which were split by `", "` .

My code is,

`df['col1'] = df.col1.str.split().apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1]))`

But it reverses all rows even the names were split by `" "`.

```
ID   col1
1    Owen, Michael
2    Curry, Stephen
3    Lionel, Messi
4    LeBron, James
```

Then I tried

`df.loc[df['col1'].str.contains(", ").split("col1")].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1]))`

It gives me an error,

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversing names in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663258/reversing-names-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['col1']=( df.col1.str.split()
              .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1]).rstrip(','))
              .where(df['col1'].str.contains(','),df['col1']) )
```

---

```
   ID           col1
0   1   Michael Owen
1   2  Stephen Curry
2   3  Lionel, Messi
3   4  LeBron, James
```

---

If you want drop `','`

```
df['col1']=( df.col1.str.split()
              .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1]).rstrip(','))
              .where(df['col1'].str.contains(','),df['col1']) 
              .str.replace(',','') )
```

---

```
   ID           col1
0   1   Michael Owen
1   2  Stephen Curry
2   3  Lionel  Messi
3   4  LeBron  James
```

Answer (score 3):

> It gives me an error,

This is because `str.contains(", ")` returns a boolean series, and it has no method `split`.

In any case, try

```
df.col1.str.split(',').str[1] + ',' + df.col1.str.split(',').str[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix your code `np.where`

```
df['col1']=np.where(df.col1.str.contains(','),df.col1.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1])),df.col1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to put in a comma into the `split()` like so:

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[::-1]))
```

If you want to reverse and drop the ',' then remove it from the `join` method.

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I chose to present the final values without the comma.  If you need a comma, change the `join` string from `' '` to `', '`.  I added these answers because:

1. There is no need to use `apply` in order to reverse the list when `str[::-1]` does the job
2. There is no need to use `apply` or any other trick when splitting on comma `','` will produce a list either way and reversing a one element list is the same list.  That implies that my method is safe to run on the names with no commas.  I don't need an if/then construct.
3. I deal with potential spaces in two different ways.

   1. With regex
   2. With `str.strip`

---

#### Regex and `pandas.Series.str` ...

... chained 3 times

```
#                          regex expression  
#                          split on comma
#                          followed by zero
#                          or more spaces
#                               /--\
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.split(',\s*').str[::-1].str.join(' ')

df

   ID           col1
0   1   Michael Owen
1   2  Stephen Curry
2   3   Lionel Messi
3   4   LeBron James
```

---

#### comprehension and `str.strip`

```
df['col1'] = [' '.join([*map(str.strip, x.split(','))][::-1]) for x in df.col1]

df

   ID           col1
0   1   Michael Owen
1   2  Stephen Curry
2   3   Lionel Messi
3   4   LeBron James
```